# Body content jumps UP once header changes its position to fixed. I need a solution for it (JS)

Tags: javascript

Basically, .fixed class is added to the .header on scroll event. When that happens, body content jumps up to re-adjust because header is no longer on the top of it. I think I've found the easiest solution for it, which is to simply add padding-top (same height as header) to the body once header becomes fixed. I'm just not sure how to implement it in JS.

```js
var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
var logoContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('header')[0];

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollPosition >= 100) {
        logoContainer.classList.add('fixed');
    } else {
        logoContainer.classList.remove('fixed');
    }

});
```

```css
.fixed {

position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Your code works well for me.

Comment: Wdym? The code works but you need to pay attention when header becomes fixed. Content will jump up, just try scrolling down slower and you will notice it.

Comment: I also meant it. The content in the header does not bounce when scrolling, and  is saved perfectly.

Comment: Not "content in the header", but body content of the website.

Comment: Ah .. now I understand what you mean. Yes, this is exactly how `position: fixed` works. There is no such problem with the `position: sticky`.

Comment: position: sticky fixed this problem! Are there any downsides to position: sticky instead of fixed? Will it work on old browsers?

Comment: Everything is well described here + comparisons with fixed positioning + examples in javascript - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the class to the header element, add it to the body. Then control the .header css as a child of the new class on body. And also add the padding-top to the new body class

```
.fixed-header .header{
    position: fixed;
}

.fixed-header{
    padding-top:100px;
}





var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    scrollPosition = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollPosition >= 100) {
        document.body.classList.add('fixed-header');
    } else {
        document.body.classList.remove('fixed-header');
    }

});
```